# Deleting files from the users profile when uninstalling an Inno based setup

Tags: c++, installation, inno-setup

Is it possible to delete files from this folder and how?

Currently i have this which doesnt work

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{userappdata}\Roaming\Myapp\*";
Type: files; Name: "{commonappdata}\Roaming\Myapp\*";
Type: files; Name: "{app}\*.*";

[Code]
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function GetUninstallString(): String;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function IsUpgrade(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetUninstallString() <> '');
end;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function UnInstallOldVersion(): Integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
// Return Values:
// 1 - uninstall string is empty
// 2 - error executing the UnInstallString
// 3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString

  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  // get the uninstall string of the old app
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString();
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep=ssInstall) then
  begin
    if (IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      UnInstallOldVersion();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: NEVER EVER do a blanket wildcard delete on a folder like `{app}`!! What if the user installed into `C:\Windows\`? Congratulations, you've just wiped out their Windows installation on an upgrade.

Comment: Oh, and are you sure you have `{userappdata}\Roaming` and `{commonappdata}\Romaing`? `{userappdata}` is already in the roaming profile and `{commonappdata}` is system specific and a roaming folder makes no sense.

Comment: @Deanna It would only delete files from your app inside Windows dir and not entire windows, but since you mention, if they are that techdumb their Windows would be gone soon anyway

Comment: [UninstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{commonappdata}\Myapp\*"; seems to work, will this delete \loggedinuseradminorlimited\appdata\roaming\app\content...? or only for admin?

Comment: @Marko29: If you keep the `[UninstallDelete] {app}\*` in there, then it will indeed delete all of Windows, not just files from your app.  Which is exactly why that sort of wildcard is a bad idea.

Comment: @Marko29: `{commonappdata}` is not in or part of a user profile, what you asked makes no sense. `{userappdata}` is ONLY the current users profile. Nothing else, it doesn't magically evaluate to all the user's profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Inno can remove files from the profile of the user running the uninstaller, it can not touch any other user's profile.

If the user trying to run the uninstaller is a limited user, it will ask for the admin details and so any `{user...}` constants will resolve to the admin user, NOT the limited user.

Your best option in this case is it leave any of the user's configuration and data in case they want to reinstall or have roaming profiles. Also note that in your code above, the old setup is removed during the upgrade which will trigger the "remove all the user's data" option. I'm sure that's not what you want...

Comment: While i generally agree with this its not really helping me, sorry. First of all i would only include removal of user data when there is a need for that eg: settings file stored in that folder becomes so different that it can cause app to crash if not removed. It sickens me that if you store settings in your app folder most windows configuration will not let your app write to that file and if you save this file in settings folder you are not able to delete it, Jesus!

Comment: You can delete it if it's global (which is the equivalent of in the app folder. Just per user is impossible as many users may have run it, and the file may be on lots of locations, maybe other machines. Besides, you should fix your app to not crash if the settings are invalid :)